# Объектный полиморфизм

Tags: c++, qt, полиморфизм

Есть `QTabWidget tabs`. В нем лежат виджеты вкладок, в каждой вкладке есть layout, в этом layout'e `QScrollArea` со своим layout'om.
И при получении конкретной вкладки в любой другой функции я пишу `QWidget* tab = new tabs->widget(0)`. И мне нужно поместить на эту вкладку в layout `QScrollArea` виджеты и чтобы не писать 
`tab->layout()->widget->layout()->addWidget(someWidget)`
я хочу перегрузить функцию layout(), чтобы для вызова
`tab->layout()` возвращался сразу layout внутри `QScrollArea`, но в `QWidget функция layout()` не виртуальная, поэтому при 
`tab->layout()` 
все равно возвращается первый layout в виджете вкладки.
Можно это как-нибудь обойти без 
`dynamic_cast<Tab*>(tab)->layout()`

Comment: Вы бы лучше куски кода привели, чем на пальцах объясняли что там кого вызывает и кто там кого получает. Совершенно нечитаемо.

Answer (score 0):

Если функция не виртуальная, то обычными способами ее перегрузить не получиться, но можно попробовать перекрыть ее. Унаследовать класс и в дочерний класс добавить метод с той же семантикой, он и перекроет ее.
Вот пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    std::string get()
    {
        return "A::get";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    std::string get()
    {
        return "B::get";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << B().get() << '\n';
}
```

Результат http://ideone.com/sFtqKH Но если обьект по полиморфизму станет родительским, то вызовется метод класса А

Comment: В том то и дело, что при полиморфизме даже если функция "перекрыта", то вызовется все равно метод родительского класса.